# IOS 13, CoreNFC. What does NFCError Code=100 "Stack Error" mean?

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I want to read the information from eChip (UKR biometric international passport) using coreNFC

I have iPhone with iOS13 beta3 and XCode 11.0 beta 3.
When I scan passport I have managed to get response on delegate method :

```
    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag])
```

But when I call:

```
session.connect(to: tag)
```

I get error:

```
[CoreNFC] 00000002 83bfcc80 -[NFCTagReaderSession _connectTag:error:]:553  Error Domain=NFCError Code=100 "Stack Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stack Error, NSUnderlyingError=0x281bb0240 {Error Domain=nfcd Code=28 "Tag Not Found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Tag Not Found}}}
```

here is how I create session

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {

        guard NFCTagReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Scanning Not Supported",
                message: "This device doesn't support tag scanning.",
                preferredStyle: .alert
            )
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        sessionTAG = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443, .iso15693, .iso18092], delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        sessionTAG?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it."
        sessionTAG?.begin()

    }
```

here is my entitlements

```
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string>
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
```

and my plist file

```
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>A0000002471001</string>
        <string>00000000000000</string>
    </array>
```

Can you please help me to find out what does that error mean and what did I do wrong?

Comment: The error description says "tag not found".

Comment: but how could it be ?  I call sessionTAG?.connect(to: tag) inside tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]). And before that its perfectly recognised as NFCISO7816Tag

Comment: Any luck with this since?

Comment: Actually its start working after iOS 13 final release.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with an Spanish passport and an Iphone 7 with latest stable release (13.1.3). It is working in an iPhone Xr with beta 13.2 (But also worked with all previous betas) It may be a device related thing?